# Read node value in array using XDocument class

Tags: c#

I have below xml.How can I get FileTypeId,EngName,JpnName in an array if I have FolderName. For eample if I have Test2, I want to get 2, EngName2, JpnName2 in an array of string using XDocument class.

```
<Row>
    <FolderName>Test1</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>1</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName1</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName1</JpnName>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <FolderName>Test2</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>2</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName2</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName2</JpnName>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <FolderName>Test3</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>3</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName3</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName3</JpnName>
  </Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with LINQ:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

string yourCondition = "Test2";
var query = from elem in xdoc.Root.Elements("Row")
            where elem.Element("FolderName").Value == yourCondition
            select new
            {
                FileTypeId = elem.Element("FileTypeId").Value,
                EngName = elem.Element("EngName").Value,
                JpnName = elem.Element("JpnName").Value
            };

if (query.Count() > 0)
{
    var result = query.First();

    // You can access the fields through this:
    string engName = result.EngName;
    string fileTypeId = result.FileTypeId;
    string jpnName = result.JpnName;
}
```

And as "snn brn" pointed out, you need a Root element in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

you need main root,

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");


<Rows>
  <Row>
    <FolderName>Test1</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>1</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName1</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName1</JpnName>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <FolderName>Test2</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>2</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName2</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName2</JpnName>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <FolderName>Test3</FolderName>
    <FileTypeId>3</FileTypeId>
    <EngName>EngName3</EngName>
    <JpnName>JpnName3</JpnName>
  </Row>
</Rows>
```